# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping

I have table called category which has parent category field. I am using that field to get the sub categories. I have checked the answer for the similar question, the suggestion was (fetch = FetchType.EAGER). But I want to load it as LAZY because it is circular dependency. (Pointing to the same table again).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_NAME", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATED", nullable = false)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String uuid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_CATEGORY_ID")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory")
    private Collection<Category> subCategories = new LinkedHashSet<Category>();
}
```

The error is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.hemanths.expense.manager.api.hibernate.entity.Category.subCategories, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
```

Can someone help me find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace, it looks like this is a session management issue. Try looking at where you are opening your session, and what SessionContext you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch a collection of objects that are annotated to be lazy loaded and you don't want to convert the loading mechanism to eager, then you will have to fetch the collection in the same `session` or `transaction` that you are fetching your parent object in it by only calling the `size()` method for your collection, for example if you have a service method like this:

```
public Category getCategortById(int id) {
  Category category = categoryDao.getCategortById(id);
  category.getSubCategories().size();  // Hibernate will fetch the collection once you call the size()
}
```

Also, If you want a cleaner way for it, you can use `Hibernate.initalize()` method, to initialize any lazy loading object or collection, so it could be like this

```
 public Category getCategortById(int id) {
  Category category = categoryDao.getCategortById(id);
  Hibernate.initialize(category.getSubCategories());
}
```

You can check more on Initializing collections [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

if I say Hibernate.initialize(category.getSubCategories()); it doesn't load lazily. 

And because it is interdependency the parentCategory will have the subCategories and each sub category will have the parentCategory again. it continue infinitely.

Comment: Sorry, is this what happens now?

Comment: Yes. That's why I wanted to load **lazily**.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood something, the `Eager` loading is what is happening if you just fetched the object from the database, then all its children will be fetched, `lazy` loading is on the other hand means that you need to trigger children to fetch them once you fetch the parent, the `Hibernate.initialize()` is the trigger here. and as I said it should happen in the Transaction/Session, please read more about the `eager` and `lazy` loading here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching